# Better way of calculating document Similarity using Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, similarity

I’m indexing a collection of documents using Lucene by specifying TermVector at indexing time.
Then I retrieve terms and their frequencies by reading the index and calculating TF-IDF score vectors for each document. Then, using the TF-IDF vectors, I calculate pairwise cosine similarity between documents using [Wikipedia's cosine similarity equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

This is my problem: Say I have two identical documents “A” and “B” in this collection (A and B have more than 200 sentences). If I calculate pairwise cosine similarity between A and B it gives me cosine value=1 which is perfectly OK. But if I remove a single sentence from Doc “B”, it gives me cosine similarity value around 0.85 between these two documents. The documents are almost similar but cosine values are not. I understand the problem is with the equation that I’m using.

Is there better way / equation that I can use for calculating cosine similarity between documents?

**Edited**

This is how I calculate Cosine Similarity, `doc1[]` and `doc2[]` are TF-IDF vectors for corresponding document. the vector contains only the `scores` but not the `words`

```
private double cosineSimBetweenTwoDocs(float doc1[], float doc2[]) {
    double temp;
    int doc1Len = doc1.length;
    int doc2Len = doc2.length;
    float numerator = 0;
    float temSumDoc1 = 0;
    float temSumDoc2 = 0;
    double equlideanNormOfDoc1 = 0;
    double equlideanNormOfDoc2 = 0;
    if (doc1Len > doc2Len) {
        for (int i = 0; i < doc2Len; i++) {
            numerator += doc1[i] * doc2[i];
            temSumDoc1 += doc1[i] * doc1[i];
            temSumDoc2 += doc2[i] * doc2[i];
        }
        equlideanNormOfDoc1=Math.sqrt(temSumDoc1);
         equlideanNormOfDoc2=Math.sqrt(temSumDoc2);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < doc1Len; i++) {
            numerator += doc1[i] * doc2[i];
            temSumDoc1 += doc1[i] * doc1[i];
            temSumDoc2 += doc2[i] * doc2[i];
        }
         equlideanNormOfDoc1=Math.sqrt(temSumDoc1);
         equlideanNormOfDoc2=Math.sqrt(temSumDoc2);
    }

    temp = numerator / (equlideanNormOfDoc1 * equlideanNormOfDoc2);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I guess something is wrong about your code. Removing one sentence from 200 sentences should give you a number > 0.98. To verify it, you can generate a random vector, make a modification to the vector and compute the cosine similarity for it to see what you get. For a vector of size 1000, and random numbers in the range [10,100], if I subtract a random number in the range [10,20] from all the numbers in the vector, the resulting similarity measure is always > 0.98 for me.

Comment: I used Mathematica to verify the case. Here is my code: a = RandomInteger[{10, 100}, 1000]; b = 
 a - RandomInteger[{10, 20}, 1000]; {Total[a], Total[b], Total[a - b],
  N[(a.b)/(Norm[a] Norm[b])]}, and here is the output: {55419, 40271, 15148, 0.98811}

Comment: @Mohsen Removing One sentences from the Vector B will reduce the number of elements in that vector, if we get a vector of size 1000 after removing sentences the size of vector B will become say 995, and now vector A is size of 1000 but, two vectors are not aligned too. By removing a sentence, the vector elements are removed from middle but not from end of the vector. So if you can try by removing  vector elements from middle, you can observe 0.85 value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I told you in my comment, I think you made a mistake somewhere. 
The vectors actually contain the `<word,frequency>` pairs, not `words` only.
Therefore, when you delete the sentence, only the frequency of the corresponding words are subtracted by 1 (the words after are not shifted).
Consider the following example:

Document a:

```
A B C A A B C. D D E A B. D A B C B A.
```

Document b:

```
A B C A A B C. D A B C B A.
```

Vector a:

```
A:6, B:5, C:3, D:3, E:1
```

Vector b:

```
A:5, B:4, C:3, D:1, E:0
```

Which result in the following similarity measure:

```
(6*5+5*4+3*3+3*1+1*0)/(Sqrt(6^2+5^2+3^2+3^2+1^2) Sqrt(5^2+4^2+3^2+1^2+0^2))=
62/(8.94427*7.14143)=
0.970648
```

**Edit**
I think your source code is not working as well. Consider the following code which works fine with the above example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DocumentVector {
    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void incCount(String word) {
        Integer oldCount = wordMap.get(word);
        wordMap.put(word, oldCount == null ? 1 : oldCount + 1);
    }

    double getCosineSimilarityWith(DocumentVector otherVector) {
        double innerProduct = 0;
        for(String w: this.wordMap.keySet()) {
            innerProduct += this.getCount(w) * otherVector.getCount(w);
        }
        return innerProduct / (this.getNorm() * otherVector.getNorm());
    }

    double getNorm() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (Integer count : wordMap.values()) {
            sum += count * count;
        }
        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }

    int getCount(String word) {
        return wordMap.containsKey(word) ? wordMap.get(word) : 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String doc1 = "A B C A A B C. D D E A B. D A B C B A.";
        String doc2 = "A B C A A B C. D A B C B A.";

        DocumentVector v1 = new DocumentVector();
        for(String w:doc1.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")) {
            v1.incCount(w);
        }

        DocumentVector v2 = new DocumentVector();
        for(String w:doc2.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")) {
            v2.incCount(w);
        }

        System.out.println("Similarity = " + v1.getCosineSimilarityWith(v2));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm removing the sentences manually from Doc "B" and then do the indexing with Lucene. So for your example, in Doc "B" Lucene dosen't know that there was a term "E" in the document "B" previously.

Comment: Take this example Doc A{ABCEEBC. DDEEB. DEBCBE} Doc B{DDEEB.DEBCBE} So now Vector A{A-1,B-5,C-3,D-3,E-6} (Vector A Size=5); Vector B{B-3,C-1,D-3,E-4} (Vector B Size=4). So this shows actually terms are shifted, so it will be comparing Term- "A" from vector A with Term "B" of vector B. This outputs cosine value around ~0.7. Is there a way of removing sentences AFTER indexing in Lucene?

Comment: @Kasun: I myself have implemented the cosine similarity measure a few years ago as I described you and it used to work perfectly. The problem is that you think the words must be shifted while they must not. This is true that vectors a and b in the above example are not of a same size, but if a term does not exist in a vector, its frequency is simply supposed to be zero. So, the frequency of term E in document a is 1 while its frequency in document b is 0 (because it doesn't exist).

Comment: Lucene doesn't need to know whether it was deleted or has never existed at all. As an additional example the frequency of the term F (or any other one that is not in either of the documents) is 0 both in vector a and b. I am pretty sure you are using Lucene in a wrong way. Could you please edit your question and add a minimal code snippet that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I have edited the question with my cosine similarity calculation code. Please check.